# Argument list is too long error only when I specify the directory in the du command

Tags: bash, disk-usage

I am trying to calculate the total size of particular files in a directory 
(e.g. `/mydirectory/data/` )
So, after `cd` to this specific directory, I use the following command:

```bsh
du -c *.bin | grep total | awk '{print$1+0}'
```

The command worked as expected. However when I try:

```bsh
du -c /mydirectory/data/*.bin | grep total | awk '{print$1+0}'
```

I get the error message

```
bash: /usr/bin/du: Argument list too long
```

It is the same directory, so why did it work in the first case and in the second it didn't? Are there any extra expansion in the second case? It is exactly the same directory, with the same number of files...

The problem is that I need to put this command in a large `bash` script, therefore it is not convenient to `cd` to directories every time and then again back etc.

Comment: You just hit ARG_MAX.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your chain by piping the output of `du` only to `grep`?

Comment: Why I hit ARG_MAX only in the second case? It is the same directory, with the same files.

Comment: When I pipe the output of  ```du``` only to ```grep```, I got the same message.

Comment: @MariosK. Yes, because the issue is not with `awk` but with the expansion of the globbing pattern.

Comment: They are the same files, except for every one of them having an 18-character prefix in the second case. The limit is a text length, not a number of args.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Argument list too long" error occurs when the expanded list of arguments becomes too long, i.e. when the length of the string consisting of all filenames given as arguments (combined with the length of all environment variables and their values) grow beyond a certain number of bytes.

You don't get this error with your first command, because you're lucky.

You do get this error with your second command, because now *each argument* also includes the string `/mydirectory/data/`, which means that the argument list grows by at least 18 bytes *per argument*, or 18 kB per 1000 files.

You could work around this by first doing a `cd /mydirectory/data`:

```
( cd /mydirectory/data/ && du -c *.bin ... )
```

(the parenthesis means that the `cd` only changes the current directory for that one command, so there is no need to "`cd` back")

This would work for now, but would still break if you add many more files matching `*.bin`.  In that case, you may want to use a slightly more complicated approach:

```
find /mydirectory/data -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.bin' -exec du -c {} + |
awk '/total/ { sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
```

This runs `du` on as many files *as possible* in your directory, in batches.  The `grep` is incorporated into the `awk` program (there's never a good reason to feed `awk` with the output of `grep`), and the `awk` program now does a simple sum that is outputted at the end.

We need the `awk` program to do a sum, because the `du` command will be executed more than one time, generating multiple `total` lines.

Answer (score -1):

```
find /mydirectory/data -iname "*.bin" -maxdepth  1 |xargs du -c |
awk '{print $1 }'|xargs |tr " " "+" |bc
```